# Get currently selected text field ID and add text to it through a numberpad

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield, numpad

So, I have this table where I have text field beside each product and I am to input the value in any selected text field via a number pad( buttons from 0-9). I need to know how can I get the id value of currently selected text field, and add numbers as text to it using the numberpad.

Comment: Any code would be good. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.id` to get the `ID` of the particular element. For example, when I have done a snippet that says the ID once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```html
<input id="this-is-id"
       onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) alert(this.id);" />
```